# Customize Laravel error reporting to remove stack trace

Tags: php, laravel

How can you turn off or remove the stack traces from Laravel's error reports. They're annoying if you want to read them in your console. I know you can add a custom handler in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 24):

Setting `APP_DEBUG=false` in your `.env` file works fine for the frontend.

If you don't want the stack trace lines to be outputted in the log files only, try this.

In `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` add `use Log;` at the top, then add this in the report function:

```
Log::error('['.$e->getCode().'] "'.$e->getMessage().'" on line '.$e->getTrace()[0]['line'].' of file '.$e->getTrace()[0]['file']);
```

And remove:

```
parent::report($e);
```

More info: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-stacktrace-from-log-files

Answer (score 10):

Since I can not comment on or edit @Harold answer, here is a improved sollution:

1. In /app/Exceptions/Handler.php add use Log; at the top,
2. Then modify the report function:

```
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if (!config('app.debug')) {
            Log::error('['.$e->getCode().'] "'.$e->getMessage().'" on line '.$e->getTrace()[0]['line'].' of file '.$e->getTrace()[0]['file']);
        } else {
            parent::report($e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't like "add this, remove that" kind of instructions, here's what `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` should look like, based on Laravel 5.7, and sticking to a message format like PHP's native one:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Log;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;


class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        Log::error(sprintf(
            "Uncaught exception '%s' with message '%s' in %s:%d",
            get_class($exception),
            $exception->getMessage(),
            $exception->getTrace()[0]['file'],
            $exception->getTrace()[0]['line']
        ));
        // parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Note that you can replace `Log::error()` with a simple call to `error_log()` to write to PHP's standard error log. If you do that, you don't have to remove the call to `parent::report()`. That way you can keep the traces in the Laravel log for further debugging, but keep your main PHP log for quick checks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to edit the log format in your logging config file. This means you don't have to override the default `report` function which would mean missing out on other logic within the parent function.

I set mine to this:

```
 'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'formatter' =>LineFormatter::class,
        'formatter_with' => [
            'format' => "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message%\n %context%\n",
            'dateFormat' => "Y-m-d H:i:s"
        ],
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        'days' => 14,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but I spent a while finding an elegant solution for this. For papertrail at least a custom handler works really well:

```php
'papertrail' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    'handler' => env('LOG_PAPERTRAIL_HANDLER', \Support\Logging\CustomSyslogUdpHandler::class),
    'handler_with' => [
        'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
        'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
        'connectionString' => 'tls://'.env('PAPERTRAIL_URL').':'.env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
    ],
    'processors' => [PsrLogMessageProcessor::class],
],
```

```php
<?php

namespace Support\Logging;

use Monolog\LogRecord;

class CustomSyslogUdpHandler extends \Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler
{
    protected function write(LogRecord $record): void
    {
        if($record->context['exception'] ?? null) {
            $record->formatted = $this->formatRecordWithoutTrace($record->toArray());
        }

        parent::write($record);
    }

    protected function formatRecordWithoutTrace(array $record): string
    {
        $exception = $record['context']['exception'];

        return sprintf(
            "[%s] %s.%s: %s",
            $record['datetime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            $record['channel'],
            strtoupper($record['level_name']),
            $exception->getMessage()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

simplely set your `APP_DEBUG=false` in your env file.

Comment: I want the stack trace not to show in my log files. This is not working

Comment: this will disable reporting errors to application. But still error will be logged

Answer (score -6):

Harold and Jani's answers are correct.

However the log line is less detailed than the default one.

The best solution would be to edit the file:

> vendor/laravel/frameworks/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php

and add **false** argument when the includeStacktraces method is called.

add false to

> $formatter->includeStacktraces();

so:

> $formatter->includeStacktraces(false);

This will simply disable the stacktrace. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: The "best solution" never involves editing a file in the vendor subdirectory.

Comment: And all changes need to be done again if you need to update ```composer dependencies```