# How to correctly report custom exceptions in Laravel 8.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to throw a custom exception and then later render it to users in a easy-to-read format. The issue comes with logging the exception in the Laravel logs.

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#renderable-exceptions) I can use the `report()` function to log the exception however, I cannot seem to get the exception trace as no argument is supplied to the method.

To this effect, I tried to use the `context()` function and return `$this->getMessage()` like you would use `$e->getMessage()` however, this returns null.

**I'd like to log the error and what line and file the error occurred in.**

To invoke the exception, I use:

```
throw_unless(
    strlen($state) > 0 && $state === $request->state,
    SSOException::class # Single-Sign-On oAuth 2.0
);
```

My custom exception looks like this:

```
class SSOException extends Exception
{
    public function report()
    {
        # This never gets executed - Logs are always empty
        Log::warn("Sign-Sign-On: {$this->getMessage()} on line {$this->getLine()}.");
    }
    
    public function render(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        if($request->user())
        {
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::logout();
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        }

        return view('exceptions.sso', [
            'context' => $this->context(),
        ]);
    }
    
    public function context()
    {
        return [
            'request' => request()->all(),
            'exception' => $this->getMessage(), # null
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to extend ExceptionHandler not Exception. Here is a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523610/creating-a-custom-exception-class-and-custom-handler-class-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583567/customize-laravel-error-reporting-to-remove-stack-trace Basically you override `App\Exceptions\Handler::report()` to remove the call to `parent::report()` and replace it with your own method. You could make this conditional on the exception object being a certain class, or having a `report()` method.

Comment: Thanks. This worked and it safely reports to the logs whilst displaying a safe error page. @miken32